# Find all possible lengths of the final sequences.

Tags: combinatorics

Sequence, started from $WW$ and using the following rule :

$WW \rightarrow BWB$

$BW \rightarrow WWB$

$WB \rightarrow BWW$

$BB \rightarrow WWW$

and the final sequences do not contain $B$.

Find all possible lengths of the final sequences.

My attempted work :

$WW \rightarrow BWB \rightarrow WWBB \rightarrow  WWWWW $

$WW \rightarrow BWB \rightarrow BBWW \rightarrow  WWWWW $

Lengths of the final sequences $\geq 5$ but I don't know how to find all the possible lengths.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: I kinda don't agree with your expansions, should'nt WW expand to BWB at some point ?

Comment: Once you have WWWWW, you can apply the WW->BWB again, etc.  so basically replace any WW with WWWWW ... and you can keep this going indefinitely. So this gives you lengths of 2,5,8,11,....

Comment: I don't understand why $WWBB\to WWWWW$.  I don't think the rules are clear.

Comment: Are you doing back and forth expansions ? Starting encoding from the tail, then from the head, then from the tail and so on. This is the only way to get what's written, thus my question about it being the general process we have to consider ? This is different from expanding always from the tail or always from the head.

Comment: I don't think the rules are clear.  You appear to follow your transformation rules capriciously.  If you can, edit your post to explain precisely how a word is transformed.  If you can't, I think the question should be closed.

Comment: @lulu, my work just show the shortest length, excluding WW, that do not contain B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that any $WW$ can be transformed into $WWWWW$ ... Which means that you can keep adding 3 more $W$'s to any string of W's. Hence, you can definitely get strings of length $2,5,8,11...$, i.e. $2+3n$ for any natural number $n$ (I would include $WW$ itself as an end string)

The more tricky part is to show that you cannot get any other length string ...

Here is a proof:

First of all, note that the number of $B$'s in your string will always be even, since you start out with $0$ $B$'s, and every rule either keeps the number of $B$'s the same, adds $2$ $B$'s, or subtracts $2$ $B$'s.

Now, define:

$n$: the number of pairs of $B$'s

$p$: the number of $W$'s that are outside a pair of $B$'s where you pair up the $B$'s from left to right

$q$: the number of $W$'s that are inside a pair of $B$'s where you pair up the $B$'s from left to right

Example: If your string is:

$$\color{red}{WWW}B\color{blue}{WW}B\color{red}{WW}BB$$

Then $n=2$ (two pairs of $B$'s), $q=2$ (these are the blue ones: $2$ $W$'s inside first pair of $B$'s + $0$ $W$'s inside second pair), and $p=5$ (these are the red $W$'s)

Now we can prove by induction the following claim:

When starting with $WW$, and applying any of the rules any number of times, the following is true:  $3n+p+2q = 2 + 3k$ for some natural number $k$ (or: $2n+p+3q \equiv 2 \mod 3$)

Base:  At the start, i.e. where we have $WW$, we have $n=0$, $p=2$, and $q=0$, so $3n+p+2q = 2$. Check!

Step: Assume for some string we have $p$, $q$, and $r$ are defined as above, and let's assume by inductive hypothesis that  $3n+p+2q = 2 + 3k$ for some natural number $k$. Now we apply any of the rules, and let's say that these values for the new string are $n'$, $p'$, and $q'$ respectively. So, we want to show that whatever rule rule is applied, and to whatever part of the string we apply it, $3n'+p'+2q' = 2 + 3k'$ for some natural number $k'$.

So, we have 4 cases to consider:

1. We apply $WW \rightarrow BWB$

This case splits into 2 further cases:

a. The $WW$ that is being replaced is inside a pair of $B$'s.  Then applying the rule means that:

$n'=n+1$ (We add 1 pair of $B$'s)

$p'=p+1$ (given that the $WW$ was inside a pair, the $W$ in the $BWB$ we add adds up being outside a pair ... so we add one of those)

$q'=q-2$ (given that the $WW$ was inside a pair and we remove those, and given that the added $W$ ends up being outside a pair, we decrease the number of $W$'s inside a pair by $2$)

So:

$$3n'+p'+2q'=3(n+1)+p+1+2(q-2)=3n+3+p+1+2q-4=$$

$$3n+p+2q=2+3k$$. Check!

b. The $WW$ that is being replaced is outside a pair of $B$'s.  Then applying the rule means that $n'=n+1$, $p'=p-2$, and $q'=q+1$. So:  $3n'+p'+2q'=3(n+1)+p-2+2(q+1)=3n+3+p-2+2q+2=3n+p+2q+3=2+3k+3=2+3(k+1)$. Check!

2. The rule we apply is $BW \to WWB$

(left to OP)

3. The rule we apply is $WB \to BWW$

(Proof by 'left to OP' :) )

4. The rule we apply is $BB \to WWW$

(Proof by OP)

Since we have now proven the claim, let's consider what happens when we have a string with no $B$'s:  that means $n=0$, $q=0$, and $p$ is the length of the string. Because of the claim we just proved, we have $3n+p+2q=p=2+3k$. Therefore, any string you can obtain that has no $B$'s will have to be of length $2+3k$.  Since we can obtain all such strings, we now know exactly which lengths we can obtain: all and only those of length $2+3k$ for some natural number $k$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give me some suggestion on how to show that there would be no other length besides 3n+2 ?

Comment: @carat Just added that to my post :) I did the first case, and left the other 3 to you!

Comment: @carat There was indeed  a slight mistake in 1a.  The RHS should be 2+3k since it ends up being exactly 3n+p+2q which by inductive hypothesis was assumed to be 2+3k.  Were you able to complete all the other cases?

Comment: Thank you, Bram28. I understand subcase 1b, but in subcase 1a, why is 3n'+p'+2q' still equal to P(k) ?  If I'm clear at this point, I think I can proceed for the other 3 cases.

Comment: @carat You mean: why is it not $P(k+1)$?  It's because the proof does induction over the number of times you apply any of the rules, not over $k$. And the property that is claimed to transfer from step to step is that 2 times the number of pairs of B's + 3 times the number of W's between the pairs of B's + the remaining W's will always be 2+3k for *some* number k. And in the case of 1a, it so happens that $2n'+p'+3q'=2n+p+3q$, i.e. that total remains the same, and since it was $2+3k$ by inductive hypothesis, it will remain $2+3k$, and is thus consistent with the claim.  Hope that helps ... :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Proceed from your work, the values of $3n'+p'+2q'$ for 2a, 2b, 3a, 3b, 4a, 4b are $2+3(k+1), 2+3k, 2+3k, 2+3(k+1), 2+3(k+1), 2+3k$ respectively. By the way, I wonder if this problem can be solved using Invarience. I still cannot figure out.

Comment: @carat Cool, so they all they check out!  Not familiar with Invariance myself ....  Anyway, thanks for the problem ... it was fun to figure it out! :)

Comment: I think to figure this problem out is not easy. I wonder how you can get 3n+p+2q ?

Comment: @carat Well, I was just generating some sequences, and tried to look for a pattern, and going by the hypothesis that the number of W's would always be $2 + 3k$ in the end, I was in particular looking as to how the number of B's would effect the eventual number of W's. But yes, it took me 20 minutes or so before I saw the $p$ vs $q$ distinction .. but once I was running with those variables, it was straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @carat You're quite welcome! :)